# Can I use "dead bat" as an expression outside of cricket?

Tags: word-usage

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dead_ba) offers the following definition of "dead bat":

> Noun dead bat (plural dead bats)
>
> (cricket) The bat when held with a light grip such that it gives when the ball strikes it, and the ball loses momentum and falls to the ground.

> Verb
>
> dead bat (third-person singular simple present dead bats, present participle dead batting, simple past and past participle dead batted)

I would like to use this verb in a more generalized way, to mean "to answer questions / requests in a way that reduces the momentum of the discussion while also giving little away".

Is there justification for this usage, such as published materials that assume  this usage to be valid?

Comment: I assume you're writing this for an audience familiar with cricket; most Americans, for instance, would assume you were talking about [dead animals.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bat)

Comment: Context is everything, Resistance is futile. You've got your definition. What is your context?

Comment: **Dead bat** (n. and v.) is not a well known term outside of cricket and even those with a fair or passing knowledge of the game would struggle to understand a sudden metaphorical use. -- You should not use it. (For what it's worth, Wiktionary is basically unreliable as far as obscure words go.)

Comment: Searching the BBC website, [most results](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22dead+bat%22+site%3Abbc.co.uk) are literally dead animals. But I did find "he sent one of his deputies out to dead-bat the media's questions" in a [wry article](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-26485247) by a BBC journalist. I have to agree with previous comments, it depends on your audience. But you can do your own research.

Comment: @alphabet - I would say that anyone expecting Americans to understand the expression is playing on a sticky wicket.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yeah, people using such metaphors with Americans have often struck out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term **dead bat** isn't widely understood outside the world of cricket.

I suggest using a term more commonly used in both politics and sport.
From [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/deflect):

> **deflect**
> *verb*
>
> to change direction after hitting something, or to cause something to do this
> *The crowd cheered as the goalkeeper deflected the shot.*
>
> to cause something to change direction, or to suddenly go in a different direction
> *The mayor deflected questions about his political plans.*

Comment: No. Deflection of a ball sends it somewhere else but with the same momentum. A dead bat just kills the momentum.